# Split and concatenate strings in PowerApps / Sharepoint List

Tags: string, sharepoint, powerapps

Upon clicking the "submit" button on this form (which is functional), I need to split some text from one text-field and send that value to another column in my SharePoint list.

User will enter an email in the email text-field, and I need to take the value in the string before the @ sign to create a username for the user.

Unfortunately, I'm not having any luck finding a solution for this one. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.
Create a Username column on the SharePoint List, add the field to the form you are submitting.
Then put the formula below on the Default property of the Textbox in the Datacard of the Username.

```
Left(TextInput1.Text, Find("@", TextInput1.Text) -1)
```

Where TextInput1 is the name of the Textbox of the datacard for the Email address.
You can then disable and hide the Datacard of the Username if you don't want it displayed on the form.

Let me know if you have any other questions.
Thanks

Comment: Ok, glad it did